# C Arrays: I keep getting Output: false. What's the mistake in my code?

Tags: c

This is the question prompt:

Write a program that checks if two arrays of the same length match after
some number of shifts on the first array. A shift on an array means moving the leftmost
element to the rightmost position. For example, if array a contains {4, 6, 1, 2}, then it
will be {6, 1, 2, 4} after one shift. If array b contains {1, 2, 4, 6}, then array a matches array b after 2 shifts. Your program will display “true” if and only if array a can become
array b after some number of shift on a. Your program will display “false” otherwise.

```
Example input/output #1:
Enter the length of the input array: 4
Enter the elements of the first array: 2 8 1 4
Enter the elements of the second array: 1 4 8 2
Output: false

Example input/output #2:
Enter the length of the input array: 5
Enter the elements of the first array: 4 6 7 1 3
Enter the elements of the second array: 1 3 4 6 7
Output: true

1) Name your program arrays2.c.
2) In the main function, the program will ask the user to enter the length of the
arrays and the elements of each array.
3) Include the function shift() in the program. The shift() function
moves the leftmost element of array a to the rightmost position.

void shift(int a[], int n);

4) The main function calls the shift function, evaluates the arrays, and displays
the result.
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define input
#define N 5

void shift(int a[], int n) {
int i;
int first_element = a[0];
for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
a[i-1]=a[i];
}
a[n-1] = first_element;
}

int main() {
int i, n;
int shift_counter = 0;
int first_array[100];
int second_array[100];
printf("Enter the length of the input array: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Enter the elements of the first array: ");

for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
scanf("%d", &first_array[n]);
}

printf("Enter the elements of the second array: ");

for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
scanf("%d", &second_array[n]);
}

while (shift_counter <= n) {
if (first_array == second_array) {
printf("Output: true");
break;
}
else{
if (shift_counter == n) {
printf("Output: false");
break;
}
shift_counter = shift_counter + 1;
shift(first_array, n);

}
}
return 0;
    
}
```

I get this output when i run the second sample input

```
Enter the length of the input array: 5
Enter the elements of the first array: 4
6
7
1
3
Enter the elements of the second array: 1
3
4
6
7
Output: false
```

The output should ideally be true. I am new to C and I believe arrays work differently in this language. Where I made a mistake and how I can correct it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide all necessary information directly in the question, not as external links.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<n; i++) {scanf("%d", &second_array[n]);}` Looks wrong.  You almost certainly meant to write to `second_array[i]` instead of `second_array[n]`

Comment: `first_array == second_array` is not the correct way to compare arrays in C. Use a `for` loop, for instance.

Comment: @WilliamPursell you're right, my bad. Changed it now, but looks like that wasn't the only error as my output is still the same.

Comment: Your program is poorly formatted.  Also, interactive programs require external input, opposed to expressing the problem as a function and pass in fixed test input that demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`first_array == second_array` aka `&first_array[0] == &second_array[0]` is always false as it's two distinct arrays are stored at different addresses.  This means your `while (shift_counter <= n)` increments `shift_counter` till it's `n` and exits due to `if (shift_counter == n)`.  `shift()` doesn't change the addresses of either arrays so it's irrelevant what it does (you can comment it out and have no change in external behavior).

Other problems:

1. `#define input` is not used
2. `#define N 5` is not used
3. first_array and second_array are fixed size (100 elements), but you don't check the run-time size you read in.  I.e. buffer overflow.
4. `shift()` doesn't work the way you expect.  `a[0]` is copied to `a[1]` then `a[1]` to `a[2]` means you end up with `{ a[n-1], a[0], a[0], ... }`.

Here's an working solution:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//#define DEBUG

void shift(int a[], int n) {
    int last_element = a[n-1];
    memmove(a + 1, a, sizeof(*a) * (n - 1));
    a[0] = last_element;
}

#ifdef DEBUG
void print(char *prefix, int a[], int n) {
    printf("%s", prefix);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i + 1 < n ? ", " : "\n");
    }
}
#endif

void check(int a[], int b[], int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++, shift(a, n)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        print("a: ", a, n);
        print("b: ", b, n);
#endif
        if(!memcmp(a, b, sizeof(*a) * n)) {
            printf("true");
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("\n");
#endif
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("false");
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n");
#endif
}

int main() {
    int a[] =  { 4, 6, 1, 2 };
    int a2[] =  { 6, 1, 2, 4 };
    int a3[] =  { 5, 6, 1, 2 };
  
    check(a, a2, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a));
    check(a, a3, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a));

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is `truefalse` demonstrating both a matching and non-matching run.

If you define DEBUG by changing `//#define DEBUG` to `#define DEBUG`, then the program will show you more state so you can see what is going on:

```
a: 4, 6, 1, 2
b: 6, 1, 2, 4
a: 2, 4, 6, 1
b: 6, 1, 2, 4
a: 1, 2, 4, 6
b: 6, 1, 2, 4
a: 6, 1, 2, 4
b: 6, 1, 2, 4
true
a: 6, 1, 2, 4
b: 5, 6, 1, 2
a: 4, 6, 1, 2
b: 5, 6, 1, 2
a: 2, 4, 6, 1
b: 5, 6, 1, 2
a: 1, 2, 4, 6
b: 5, 6, 1, 2
false
```